# Css colored block does not work if empty

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to draw a header composed by 2 divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #header-top {
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: #4d6186;
            }
            #header-bottom {
                padding-left: 20%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5%;
                background-color: #606060;
                box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
            }
            #logo {
                position: absolute;
                height: 25%;
            }
            #faro {
                position: absolute;
                top: 2%;
                right: 5%;
                height: 20%
            }
            #content {

            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="logo" src="img/taberna-pirata.png" alt="La taberna pirata">
        <img id="faro" src="img/faro.png">
        <div id="header-top"> </div>
        <div id="header-bottom">
            <!--<h1>Welcome to the bay</h1>-->
        </div>

        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the colored divs only work if there is something inside the div. If empty, they don't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, you can't use % values in `height`. Try using px.

Another solution is set html and body `height` as follow:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I supposed this might be the cause but, isn't that supposse to be a bad practice? How can I achieve this and still be able to see it correctly at mobile devices? Using em? different aproach and stick to the percentages?

Comment: Setting the html and body height does not work if I maintain the div heights in %

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the container element to a height. Otherwise your are asking the browser to set the height to 100% of an unknown value, and it doesn't work. In you case the container would be `body` and `html`.

Or you can add a `&nbsp;` as placeholder rather than empty. Again, that `%` won't work.

```
<div id="header-bottom">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by giving it an `absolute` position: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs2sht1p/1/)

```
#header-top {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: #4d6186;
}
```

However, I'm not sure of the reason for having an empty `div` with a percentage height.